# blank popup appear when updating mac

Tags: macos, mac

when i wanted to update the mac, this thing appear, so i can't.
maybe it's cuz of some apps that i've downloaded, but i couldn't know which one is! i need to update the mac.
i tried to search for solutions, but there's no such a problem.
please help :( i'm really suffering and bored cuz of this problem.
thanks.

10.9.5 and the model is macbook pro

EtreCheck version: 2.2 (132)
Report generated 5/31/15, 1:34 AM
Download EtreCheck from http://etresoft.com/etrecheck

Click the [Click for support] links for help with non-Apple products.
Click the [Click for details] links for more information about that line.

Hardware Information: ℹ️
    MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013) (Technical Specifications)
    MacBook Pro - model: MacBookPro11,1
    1 2.4 GHz Intel Core i5 CPU: 2-core
    4 GB RAM Not upgradeable
        BANK 0/DIMM0
            2 GB DDR3 1600 MHz ok
        BANK 1/DIMM0
            2 GB DDR3 1600 MHz ok
    Bluetooth: Good - Handoff/Airdrop2 supported
    Wireless:  en0: 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac
    Battery: Health = Normal - Cycle count = 202 - SN = D864062T07FFT5YAZ

Video Information: ℹ️
    Intel Iris
        Color LCD 2560 x 1600

System Software: ℹ️
    OS X 10.9.5 (13F1077) - Time since boot: 0:19:46

Disk Information: ℹ️
    APPLE SSD SD0128F disk0 : (121.33 GB)
        EFI (disk0s1)  : 210 MB 
        Macintosh HD (disk0s2) /  [Startup]: 120.47 GB (14.70 GB free) (Low!)
        Recovery HD (disk0s3)   [Recovery]: 650 MB

USB Information: ℹ️
    Apple Internal Memory Card Reader 
    Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad 
    Apple Inc. BRCM20702 Hub 
        Apple Inc. Bluetooth USB Host Controller

Thunderbolt Information: ℹ️
    Apple Inc. thunderbolt_bus

Gatekeeper: ℹ️
    Mac App Store and identified developers

User Launch Agents: ℹ️
    [loaded]    com.adobe.ARM.[...].plist [Click for support]
    [loaded]    com.google.keystone.agent.plist [Click for support]

User Login Items: ℹ️
    iTunesHelper    Application  (/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunesHelper.app)
    uTorrent    Application  (/Applications/uTorrent.app)
    AdobeResourceSynchronizer    Application  (/Applications/Adobe Reader.app/Contents/Support/AdobeResourceSynchronizer.app)
    RealPlayer Downloader Agent    Application  (/Users/[redacted]/Library/Application Support/RealNetworks/RealPlayer Downloader Agent.app)

Internet Plug-ins: ℹ️
    AdobePDFViewerNPAPI: Version: 11.0.07 - SDK 10.6 [Click for support]
    AdobePDFViewer: Version: 11.0.07 - SDK 10.6 [Click for support]
    QuickTime Plugin: Version: 7.7.3
    JavaAppletPlugin: Version: 14.9.0 - SDK 10.7 Check version
    Default Browser: Version: 537 - SDK 10.9

User internet Plug-ins: ℹ️
    _SpeedTaoPlugin: Version: Unknown - SDK 10.7 [Click for support]
    iGetter Plugin: Version: 2.9.2 [Click for support]
    iGetterScriptablePlugin: Version: 2.9.2 [Click for support]
    RealPlayer Plugin: Version: Unknown [Click for support]

Safari Extensions: ℹ️
    FastestTube

3rd Party Preference Panes: ℹ️
    None

Time Machine: ℹ️
    Time Machine not configured!

Top Processes by CPU: ℹ️
       100%    MPlayerX
         4%    fontd
         3%    WindowServer
         2%    Google Chrome Helper(7)
         0%    RealPlayer Downloader Agent

Top Processes by Memory: ℹ️
    991 MB    com.apple.WebKit.WebContent(11)
    381 MB    Google Chrome Helper(7)
    345 MB    kernel_task
    115 MB    Safari
    98 MB    Google Chrome

Virtual Memory Information: ℹ️
    92 MB    Free RAM 
    3.78 GB    Used RAM 
    0 B    Swap Used

Diagnostics Information: ℹ️
    May 31, 2015, 01:14:50 AM    Self test - passed
    May 29, 2015, 01:18:14 AM    /Users/[redacted]/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/VLC_2015-05-29-011814_[redacted].crash
    May 28, 2015, 04:33:09 AM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/mds_2015-05-28-043309_[redacted].crash

[image]

Comment: os x the version? 10.9.5 and the model is macbook pro - i hope u mean that-

Comment: your user profile is messed up. Get his non intrusive app and check your system.  http://www.etresoft.com/etrecheck

Comment: i downloaded it, the result has some red colour, is that where the problem came?

Comment: the red ones ? 1-      Macintosh HD (disk0s2) /  [Startup]: 120.47 GB (14.70 GB free) (Low!) 2- Time Machine not configured! 3- 100%    MPlayerX

Comment: The whole report please (all of it)

Comment: i can't, the litters aren't enough :(

Comment: Copy paste in your original post not in the comments field.

Comment: oh sorry, i did it now, please check it. i hope it'll be solved T^T

Comment: I had that once but not when updating/installing but doing something else that needed the admin password (can't remember what it was). It was confusing! Somehow it did it not again after a restart or maybe I did repair permissions with Disk Utility first. So I would first repair the boot disk's permissions and restart after that and see if it still happens.

Comment: Do you have the same blank dialog when trying to unlock System Preferences, say, in the Security pane which has a button to unlock it?

Comment: Did you try just entering your admin short-name & password?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the report

Please disable the all following (from auto starting when you log in)

> iTunesHelper Application
>   (/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunesHelper.app)

uTorrent

> Application (/Applications/uTorrent.app)

AdobeResourceSynchronizer

> Application (/Applications/Adobe
>   Reader.app/Contents/Support/AdobeResourceSynchronizer.app)

RealPlayer

> Downloader Agent Application (/Users/[redacted]/Library/Application
>   Support/RealNetworks/RealPlayer Downloader Agent.app)

How to do that:

Go to system preferences- user& groups- you will see your log in profile. Click on the Log in items and disable anything using the (-) sign to remove.

Restart your system. If the MPlayer is still running STOP it. To do that press 3 keys all together [alt (option)+ cmd +esc]. A new widow will show where you can select the MPlayer and force quit it.

**Finally lets repair your User profile.**

Hold cmd+r during restarting of the computer

You will boot into the Repair Utilities screen.

On top, in the Menu Bar click the Utilities item then select Terminal.

New window - type `resetpassword`

You will not reset the password but:

Instead, click on the icon for your Mac’s hard drive at the top. From the drop-down below it, select the user account where you are having issues.

```
At the bottom of the window, you’ll see an area labeled ‘Reset Home Directory Permissions and ACLs’. Click the Reset button there.
```

The reset process takes a couple of minutes. When it’s done, quit the programs you’ve opened and restart your Mac.

If none of the above worked I am afraid you will need to restore your Mavericks first before Installing Yosemite. To that use the cmd+r again and follow the instructions how to restore. Normally you data will not be touched during this process, but if you have back up it is better.

Comment: i removed the 4, and restart the mac, but the same empty pop-up :(

Comment: i restarted the mac to make sure, non of apps start when i restart. and i tried, but the empty pop-up .... :(